# Scala Map += operation

Tags: scala

Suppose I have next map:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
val countries = Map[String, String](
    ("Paris", "France"), 
    ("Washington", "USA"),
    ("London", "England")
)
```

Then I try to add some values to that map(I get the values from command line arguments):

```
countries += (args(0), args(1))
```

But the above code doesn't compile saying that

```
found   : String
required: (String, String)
```

When I change that to

```
countries += ((args(0), args(1)))
```

or to

```
countries += (args(0) -> args(1))
```

then it compiles successfully. Why did the compiler not recognise a tuple in first case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map):

> def
>   +=(elem1: (A, B), elem2: (A, B), elems: (A, B)*): Map.this.type
>   adds two or more elements to this shrinkable collection.

In other words, there's an overloaded version of `+=` that lets you add a number of elements at once. Your example looks like it's trying to do that (using the normal convention for multiple arguments), except that it's then complaining (rightly) that each of those arguments is of the wrong type.

Comment: but why it try to use that method? As far as I know when a method takes only one argument than it can be used without dot notation(and also without paranthese for paramater). In my case I use method += without dot notation, so next statement indicates a single parameter which is a tuple of 2 values

Comment: There's no such restriction on when something can be used without the dot notation. For example: `object A { def a(x : Int, y : Int) = x + y }`, `A a (1,2)` is perfectly valid and works as expected. The first parenthesis in your example looks like the start of the argument list.

Comment: @maks What might be confusing is that there's also something called (I think) *tuple promotion*, whereby if you pass multiple args where a single tuple arg is expected, those args will get wrapped into a tuple by the compiler. Hence `object A { def a(x: (Int, Int)) = x._1 + x._2 }` then `A a (1,2)` will also work... unless `A` has another (overloaded) method `a` which takes 2 args, in which case that gets called instead.

Comment: @Luigi is this as with varargs in java?

Comment: @maks When a method expects varargs (as is signified in the `+=` method above by the `*` symbol) then the method does not take a single tuple so tuple promotion cannot occur, and you need to supply the outer parens.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thought you were passing two parameters and interpreted your first parentheses as the delimiters of the parameter list.